# How to disable the "compile error expected end of statement" from showing in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Frequently when entering code I will type half of a line, for example the opening part of an if statement, but rather than type the second half I will want to copy and paste, both for convenience and to minimize the chance of a typing error.  However if I move the focus away from a half completed statement I get the very annoying "compile error, expected end of statement" pop up which I must acknowledge.  This is becoming very tedious when it comes up so often.

**Is there any way to tell excel not to show this error message?**

Comment: [Customize your IDE -> VBE](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/hello-world/vbe-hello-world/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When editing Microsoft Office VBA, how can I disable the popup "Compile error" messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560934/when-editing-microsoft-office-vba-how-can-i-disable-the-popup-compile-error-m)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Annoying isn't it? Click `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Editor` Tab and uncheck *Auto syntax check*